# Error Upgrading to 2.7.2

Tags: database, updating

I tried to do an upgrade to 2.7.2 using Updater but found that the version of Updater was old. Hence, it didn't work! I know it's my fault and I should have checked first.

Now when I try to login to the Control Panel I get the following error message -

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'hash' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `hash`, `timestamp` FROM (`exp_developer_log`) ORDER BY
>   `timestamp` asc
>
> Filename: libraries/Logger.php
>
> Line Number: 106

It's not critical as the site is in development, but when I get home tonight and have a chance to look at it, if I do a manual upgrade of the EE files for 2.7.2 will that solve the issue?

I do have a back up of the database before I began the upgrade and I host with enginehosting.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and mess with a failed upgrade. Revert back to previous & start again.

Given the failure point was updater I'd recommend a manual update.

Answer (score 1):

The error says the "hash" column is missing from the "exp_developer_log" table.

I suggest getting into the database using [PHPMyAdmin and manually adding a new column](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/phpmyadmin/adding-a-column-to-a-database-table-in-phpmyadmin) to that table named "hash".